# Трансляция twitch.tv в android

Tags: android, webview, потоки-данных, twitch

Делаю приложение игровой тематики, в которой одна из рубрик - прямые трансляции игр. Собственно, есть прямые адреса на стримы, к примеру http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=starladder1

Что пытаюсь сделать я:

```
final WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Результат - открывается webview в котором пишется, что надо установить flash player.. Хотя в официальном приложении twitch воспроизводится всё отлично без флэша. Понимаю, что возможно даже не в ту сторону копаю, но есть ли у кого какие догадки? Буду рад любой помощи!

Comment: по вашей ссылке http://player.twitch.tv/?channel=starladder1 трансляия воспроизводится в плеере на флеше.

Comment: Все, понял. Не нагуглил чё-то..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нашел решение для WebView. Все оказалось просто:

```
webView.loadUrl("http://www.twitch.tv/" + chanelName+ "/popout");
```

Answer (score 4):

Официальное приложение не использует WebView, а использует api твича и проигрывает видео плеером.